# HttpURLConnection post method issue

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection

I have a problem on HttpURLConnection in post method. Everything is working fine on get method however, when I try to use Post method. I'm getting this error message.
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL

Here's my code snippet. I hope you could help me about this.

```
URL url = new URL(my url/userInfo);
    String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("username:password").getBytes("UTF-8"));


    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
    connection.setRequestProperty("x-csrf-token", "fetch");
    String csrfToken = connection.getHeaderField("x-csrf-token");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    String output = in.readLine();

    in.close();

    String content = data   // expected data to retrieve


    URL url2 = new URL(my URL);//another url to push the data retrieve
    HttpURLConnection connection2 = (HttpsURLConnection) url2.openConnection();

    connection2.setDoInput(true);
    connection2.setDoOutput(true);
    connection2.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection2.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
    connection2.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    connection2.setRequestProperty("x-CSRFToken", csrfToken);
    connection2.setRequestProperty("cache-control", "no-cache");
    OutputStream os = connection2.getOutputStream();


    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");


    osw.write(data);//this is where the data will be pushed

    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
    os.close();
```

the idea is, we need first to get the x-csrf-token and data from the first link, which is okay. After GET Method execution, the POST method will occur. unfortunately, the post method is not working. I'm getting the error message shown above. By the way, we tried to do a post method in POSTMAN and it' working fine.

Hoping you could help me about this.

Comment: Can you tell us the error message please ? Does is say  `CSRF token missing or incorrect`?

Comment: check get method call give set-cookie header?

Comment: if there set-cookie header in get call response. postman save cookies & set it request header when you call post method

Comment: Hi Madhan M, Here's the error message I'm getting. Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL

Comment: Hi @sajib so Are you saying that postman saves the cookies from the get method to access the post method? Is there anyway to get a cookie-header  from get method using setRequestProperty?

Comment: in postmane see  below of save button. there is option cookie. here you can get cookie if postman save

Comment: @sajib I checked my postman and I did not see any cookies. I's just a code button.

Comment: check response header

Comment: I put this on my code but same thing.

 content-encoding →gzip
content-length →881
content-type →application/atom+xml;type=entry; charset=utf-8
dataserviceversion →2.0

this is what I'm seeig to response header.

Comment: @MadhanM I did not see any error message indicating that my CSRF token is missing or incorrect.

Comment: edit typo in your call as below **connection2.setRequestProperty("x-CSRFToken", csrfToken);**
     to **connection2.setRequestProperty("x-CSRF-Token", csrfToken);**